# Internet Explorer sempre em primeiro plano

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Estou usando IE no modo Kiosk e apareceu um erro de outro app na frente. O que gostaria de fazer é que caso apareça alguma outra janela no *Windows*, não apareça por cima da janela do IE, deixando-o sempre em primeiro plano.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar a janela do IE em modo sempre na frente através da biblioteca do windows.

Se você quer um programa que faça isso para você, eu sugiro utilizar o [TurboTop](http://www.savardsoftware.com/turbotop/). Ele é bem simples de usar, só instalar e selecionar na bandeja de ícones qual a janela você quer que fique sempre na frente.

Se quiser fazer isso programaticamente, utilize a função SetWindowPos da biblioteca do windows:
[SetWindowPos Function - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Você pode usar a biblioteca do windows em qualquer linguagem, vou dar um exemplo da utilização em python, com o modulo [Pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/), colocando a janela do Notepad sempre no topo:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow('Notepad', None)
win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, 300, 200, 0)
```

Fonte do código: [StackOverFlow - Set another program to always be on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439417/set-another-program-to-always-be-on-top)