# Como bloquear o computador via código?

Tags: c#

Estou tentando achar uma maneira de bloquear o computador do usuário e, apenas um form meu possa ficar ativo (Form de login), após o usuário digitar corretamente o login e senha o computador seria desbloqueado. Tem como fazer isso?

Todos os códigos que estou achando falam sobre bloquear a estação, e não é isso que eu procuro.

Comment: Defina "Bloquear o computador do usuário", seria impedir o usuário de fazer qualquer outra ação? abrir outros programas?

Comment: O usuário não deve conseguir fazer nada que fique fora do meu form, já vi aplicações assim. Mas bloqueando o acesso a internet já basta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você deseja é criar uma aplicação em *Kiosk Mode*. Isso não é simples de implementar. Você deve utilizar a *library* do sistema `user32.dll` para bloquear todas as teclas e atalhos que possam provocar a saída da aplicação e ocultar a barra de tarefa e botões do Windows.

Já tentei desenvolver uma aplicação do tipo utilizando um artigo do [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23955/Running-a-Web-Site-in-Kiosk-Mode-with-C), mais o projeto não foi pra frente. No exemplo utilizado no artigo, o projeto foi desenvolvido focando em computadores com Windows XP e Windows 7. Tem que verificar se funcionaria com sistemas operacionais mais atuais como o Windows 8, 8.1 e 10.

Aqui no SOPt [já tivemos apenas uma pergunta com este assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106115/internet-explorer-sempre-em-primeiro-plano).

No StackOverflow tem um pouco mais de conteúdo:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kiosk
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode