# Como desabilitar uma janela?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou procurando algum código que desabilite uma janela, e, após o usuário inserir um login e senha em meu form a janela volta a operar.

Sendo mais especifico e com um pouco de detalhe, eu já vi um programa fazer tal ação, ele trabalhava pelo PID do processo e o bloqueava. Quando o usuário tentasse mexer na aplicação bloqueada ele não conseguia, e o windows dava aquele som de quando tentamos clicar em algo que "não pode". Preciso de algo similar em meu projeto.

Já tentei procurar sobre Kiosk Mode mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, provavelmente será fechada. Dê mais detalhes com exemplos.

Comment: @wesley-nascimento Você quer desabilitar uma janela da sua aplicação? ou desabilitar qualquer outra janela que estiver aberta?

Comment: Por exemplo, o usuário está acessando o chrome, quando minha aplicação executar eu quero que bloqueie a janela do chrome. Não tem como ser mais explicativo que isso. Estava procurando sobre e vi que alguns rat's trabalham com isso ;-;

Comment: Se pessoas que provavelmente tem mais conhecimento que você, estão perguntando, é porque não está claro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui fazer o que deseja utilizando o `Kiosk Mode`, conforme havia citado na [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143006/como-bloquear-o-computador-via-c%C3%B3digo/143028#143028). No modo Kiosk você desabilita a entrada de teclas que possam fechar a sua aplicação, sendo assim a única forma de manter o comportamento que você deseja seria maximizar o formulário e colocá-lo como TopMost, abaixo o código que fiz:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace KioskMode
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
#region Imports da library user32.dll

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(string cls, string wndwText);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int cmd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern long SHAppBarMessage(long dword, int cmd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hwnd, int id);

#endregion


#region Constantes referentes à teclas

        private const int USE_ALT = 1;
        private const int USE_CTRL = 2;
        private const int USE_SHIFT = 4;
        private const int USE_WIN = 8;
        // Hot key ID tracker
        short mHotKeyId = 0;

#endregion


        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Maximiza a tela
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            // Retira a borda do formulario para evitar que o usuario arraste o form.
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            // Oculta o formulario da barra de tarefas
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            // Indica que o formulario ficara sempre a frente
            this.TopMost = true;

            // Desabilita teclas de atalho de saída da aplicação
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.F4, USE_ALT);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.W, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.N, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.S, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.A, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.C, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.X, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.V, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.B, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.F, USE_CTRL);
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys.H, USE_CTRL);

            // oculta a barra de tarefas
            ShowWindow(FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null), 0);
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtLogin.Text == "Usuario" &&
                txtSenha.Text == "Senha")
                Close();
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Login inválido");
        }

        private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void RegisterGlobalHotKey(Keys hotkey, int modifiers)
        {
            try
            {
                // increment the hot key value - we are just identifying
                // them with a sequential number since we have multiples
                mHotKeyId++;

                if(mHotKeyId > 0)
                {
                    // register the hot key combination
                    if (RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, mHotKeyId, modifiers, Convert.ToInt16(hotkey)) == 0)
                    {
                        // tell the user which combination failed to register -
                        // this is useful to you, not an end user; the end user
                        // should never see this application run
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + mHotKeyId.ToString() + " - " +
                            Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(),
                            "Hot Key Registration");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                // clean up if hotkey registration failed -
                // nothing works if it fails
                UnregisterGlobalHotKey();
            }
        }

        private void UnregisterGlobalHotKey()
        {
            // loop through each hotkey id and
            // disable it
            for (int i = 0; i < mHotKeyId; i++)
            {
                UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, i);
            }
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
            {
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // unregister the hot keys
            UnregisterGlobalHotKey();

            // show the taskbar - does not matter really
            ShowWindow(FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null), 1);

        }
    }
}
```

Se o usuário realizar o Login corretamente, a sua aplicação fecha e libera o computador para a utilização, caso contrário, fica na tela de login até o usuário realizar o login. Coloquei um botão de cancelar, pois, se o usuário não conseguir realizar o login a aplicação ficará eternamente em execução. Mais isso vai de acordo com a sua abordagem e o que você deseja realmente fazer.