# Como posso manter meu aplicativo sempre na tela cheia, sem que seja minimizado?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java que deve ficar em tela cheia e não pode ser minimizada ou dar espaço para outro aplicativo ou até mesmo o SO, de certa forma bloqueando tudo e deixando apenas ele na tela, mas estou tendo dificuldades.

Consigo deixar em tela cheia mas se eu usar Alt + Tab, ele minimiza.

Como obtenho esse comportamento?

Comment: Isso se chama *kiosk mode*. Tem algumas perguntas relacionadas aqui no SOPT (em outras linguagens), como por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143006/como-bloquear-o-computador-via-c%c3%b3digo/143028#143028

Comment: Eu não sei qual a intenção com isso Thiago, se for algo acadêmico ou regra de um determinado cliente tudo certo, mas se não for um desses dois casos deveria considerar adicionar essa opção na configuração(talvez você já vá fazer isso) para o usuário poder fazer oque quiser dentro do seu computador, pois limitar o usuário dentro do seu sistema não me parece uma boa ideá. Porem vou estar aqui esperando a resposta pois pretendo usar isso em um sistema que estou trabalhando...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127709/remove-the-possibility-of-using-alt-f4-and-alt-tab-in-java-gui/6128105#6128105

Comment: Isto não seria horrível para a experiência do usuário!?

Answer (score -3):

Para bloquear o <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> você pode usar uma forma mais agressiva:

```
public class AltTabStopper implements Runnable
{
     private boolean working = true;
     private JFrame frame;

     public AltTabStopper(JFrame frame)
     {
          this.frame = frame;
     }

     public void stop()
     {
          working = false;
     }

     public static AltTabStopper create(JFrame frame)
     {
         AltTabStopper stopper = new AltTabStopper(frame);
         new Thread(stopper, "Alt-Tab Stopper").start();
         return stopper;
     }

     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             Robot robot = new Robot();
             while (working)
             {
                  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
                  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                  frame.requestFocus();
                  try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(Exception) {}
             }
         } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(-1); }
     }
}
```

Pelo que entendi você quer isto.

Comment: Não é bem isso que o OP queria, era manter a aplicação em tela cheia, mesmo alternado de janela. Isso ai não resolve o problema, é mais complexo.